# Input Box: Type Mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

I've got a Do-While loop in VBA asking the user for their company UserID. This is used to find a folder in their personal folder, doesn't really matter that much.

I'm using an Input Box as I don't know how else I would do this:

```
Do
    filepath2 = Application.InputBox("Enter your User FDIC", "UFDIC")
    If filepath2 = False Then Exit Sub
    filepath3 = "C:\Users\" & filepath2 & "\Desktop\NSC\"
    Dir (filepath3)
Loop While Not Dir(filepath3) > ""
```

So basically, this will ask the user for UserID, if the user selects the button "Cancel", it will exit the sub.  If not, it will take the UserID and make sure it exists.
I'm getting a Type Mismatch error when it comes to the line

```
If filepath2 = False Then Exit Sub
```

due to it expecting a Boolean value, I think.

Should I be using something other than an Input Box?

If not, how do I type check?

Comment: Could not use Environ("username") to return the right username? (as a default value perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Simply have to change

```
If filepath2 = False Then Exit Sub
```

to

```
If filepath2 = "False" Then Exit Sub
```

Just changing to a String.

Comment: Not the usual solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061562/trouble-with-inputboxes  & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264814/how-to-detect-if-user-select-cancel-inputbox-vba-excel