# How to check for InputBox exit (X) vs empty string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a command button which launches an input box to allow input of a password.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  
     Dim ThePW As String

     ThePW = InputBox("A password is required to run this procedure." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please enter the password:", "Password")

     If ThePW <> "123" Then MsgBox ("wrong pw")
End Sub
```

However, when I click exit(X) or cancel, the message box still displays `wrong pw`

How can I solve this? I don't want it to display `wrong pw` when I click exit(X) or select cancel.

Comment: Try `If ThePW = "" then 'whatever  else If ThePW <> "123"`

Comment: And below the <> "123" you can add Else which means the password is correct

Comment: @evabb  have you tested the code in my answer below ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with InputBoxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061562/trouble-with-inputboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below, if he hits cancel, it just exits the `Sub`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ThePW As String

ThePW = InputBox("A password is required to run this procedure." & vbCrLf & _
"Please enter the password:", "Password")

If ThePW = "" Then Exit Sub ' Exit if null input or cancel

If ThePW <> "123" Then
    MsgBox ("wrong pw")
Else
    ' do something if OK
End If        

End Sub
```