# Object Required: Excel & Word VBA, Dictionaries, and storing ranges

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, ms-word, range

I'm in need of help in understanding why I keep getting an "object required" error at Ln82. I thought you could store anything in a dictionary?

The workflow is:

1. Start the program
2. Create the dictionary of temporary items to loop through the input box
3. Use this dictionary later to store all the user input as ranges
4. Call a sub routine to open destination document(Mysupes)
5. Call a sub routine to open source excel wb(Alert)
6. Prompt user 12 times(via loop) to select ranges in source excel
7. Paste into destination word doc(at this point I don't care where, I just need to paste the damn thing)

Also please ignore any of the comments, it is just my scratch work where I've tried different avenues.

```
Sub AlertToSupes()

'Declarations
Dim MyAlert As String
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Dim key As Variant
Dim v As Long
Dim r As Variant
Dim Mysupes As Document
'Mysupes.Visible = True
'Dim AlertToSupeData As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'Collection of objects to get from Alert doc and paste into Supes
'Dim colSupesData As Collection
'Set colSupesData = New Collection
'    colSupesData.Add "Project team names"
'    colSupesData.Add "Programming"
'    colSupesData.Add "Date(today)"
'    colSupesData.Add "Subject(Blind study name in Alert)"
'    colSupesData.Add "LRW job#"
'    colSupesData.Add "LOI"
'    colSupesData.Add "Incidence"
'    colSupesData.Add "Sample size"
'    colSupesData.Add "Dates(select from Alert)"
'    colSupesData.Add "Devices allowed"
'    colSupesData.Add "Respondent qualifications(from Alert)"
'    colSupesData.Add "Quotas"


'Dictionary of attributes(alternative to list)
dict.Add "Project team names", ""
dict.Add "Programming", ""
dict.Add "Date(today)", ""
dict.Add "Subject(Blind study name in Alert)", ""
dict.Add "LRW job#", ""
dict.Add "LOI", ""
dict.Add "Incidence", ""
dict.Add "Sample size", ""
dict.Add "Dates(select from Alert)", ""
dict.Add "Devices allowed", ""
dict.Add "Respondent qualifications(from Alert)", ""
dict.Add "Quotas", ""

'Open up the Supes

Call OpenSupes


'Open up the Alert file
MyAlert = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open (MyAlert)

'Loop for subroutine
For Each key In dict.keys
    Debug.Print (key)
    Call Cpy(key)
    dict.item = r.Value
Next key   
End Sub
```

### Sub Cpy(key As Variant)

```
'Loop that asks for user-defined input for every field of Supes
Dim r As Range, LR As Long
Dim Mysupes As Object



On Error Resume Next
Set r = Application.InputBox("Select the cell that contains " & key, Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
'LR = Cells(Rows.Count, r.Column).End(xlUp).Row
'Range(Cells(5, r.Column), Cells(LR, r.Column)).Copy Destination:=Cells(5, r.Column + 1)


r.Copy
With Mysupes
    'AppWord.Documents.Add
    AppWord.Selection.PasteExcelTable
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Set MySupes = Nothing
End With    
End Sub
```

### Sub OpenSupes()

```
'Dim Mysupes As Object
Dim wordapp As Object
Dim Mysupes As FileDialog


Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set Mysupes = Application.FileDialog( _
FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogOpen)
Mysupes.Show
'Set Mysupes = wordapp.Documents.Open("\\10.1.11.169\LRW\Field (New)\01 Admin\02 Standard Documents\01 Supes\Supes Memo - Online Study.dotx")
wordapp.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Please put Option Explicit at the top of your code and then add in all the missing variable declarations.

Comment: Also, we can't be sure which is Ln82 - please copy the line of code into your problem description that's causing the error.

Comment: And you want Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end, not the beginning of subs, and only if you switched it off at the start.

Comment: Why do you use `On Error Resume Next` where you show an InputBox? There should be no reason to do that with this function...

Comment: And be wary of opening multiple instances of Word and not closing them.

Comment: @QHarr- added Option Explicit, I feel sheepish asking but do you have resources on why one should set option explicit vs. implicit? For screen updating, this is noted. Thank you! I thought default value for screen updating was False, so I was scared and declared it.

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you! ln82 corresponds to AppWord.Selection.PasteExcelTable in the Sub Cpy() loop

removed the On Error Resume Next, so thank you. I am still learning best practices and try to build in as much error handling as possible in case shit goes wrong(which usually does with me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're reporting is generated inside your loop wen you try to assign r.Value to your dictionary

```
For Each key In dict.keys
    Debug.Print (key)
    Call Cpy(key)
    dict.item = r.Value
Next key
```

You're assuming `Cpy` subroutine is sending the r cell back to your program,
but it's not - r is declared locally in your program as a variant and locally
inside Cpy as a Range.

You need to return r as a function value instead of a closed subroutine,
or you can make the r Range type variable a global so it can be seen by all your program

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've tried to declare r globally as Range type and Object, but still get a '424 - Object required' error at the start of my loop:

For Each key In dict.keys

Comment: @JeffreyWilliamKaemmerling If you're still having problems, why did you rmark this as "the answer"? Does it answer your question, or not?

Comment: @JeffreyWilliamKaemmerling - did your remove your local declaration `Dim r As Variant` - that overrides your global

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous issues with the code.

1) Key one is that you are trying to use the `Workbooks.Open` method on a Word document. `[Workbooks.Open][1]` expects a workbook variable. So this:

```
 Workbooks.Open (MyAlert)
```

isn't going to work with a Word doc.

You want `Documents.Open` but also need a Word application to use this with so you will need to create that application instance in the appropriate sub. You do it elsewhere with `wordapp.Documents.Open`

2) Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code and declare all your variables. There are missing ones throughout.

3) Quit applications after opening them or eventually something will crash due to too many running instances.

4) `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` should be at the end of the sub to update the screen and only if you had `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before that.

5) As @CindyMeister notes: You shouldn't need an `On Error Resume Next` around `InputBox`. You can test by setting the result to a variable and testing that.See [Trouble with InputBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061562/trouble-with-inputboxes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

6) And what @dbmitch said. A function conversion would be a logical choice.

Comment: Upvoted yours as you have identified the many many problems in the current code not just answered the immediate question. I thinking fixing one problem will just lead to the next one.

Comment: Thanks from taking the time